# Building Antlr4's Java distribution fails because the test for the "antlr4 maven plugin" fails with a NullPointerException

Tags: maven, antlr4

I want to compile the ANTLR4 Java distribution using Maven. But it won't work.

I am probably going about this problem wrongly. There may be something very simple I am missing. Probably the way I'm calling Maven in the first place. The fact that absolutely no-one on the Internet seems to have this problem indicates as much.

### What happens

First, my Java version:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.3" 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.3+7 (build 17.0.3+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.3+7 (build 17.0.3+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

(But note that ANLTR4 is compiled to Java 11, except for the plugin which is compiled to Java 8, according to the POM)

So. Get the distribution from github:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/antlr/antlr4.git antlr4_30`
$ cd antlr4_30
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

Compile the projects (Maven modules)

- `runtime/Java` (the ANTLR4 *core classes*)
- `tool` (the ANTLR4 *compiler*)
- `antlr4-maven-plugin` (the *maven plugin* that runs ANTLR4 tasks)

```
PROJECTS="runtime/Java,tool,antlr4-maven-plugin"
mvn --projects "$PROJECTS" clean
mvn --projects "$PROJECTS" verify
```

Compilation works, then the tests for the *maven plugin* kick off.

These tests are run using another *maven plugin* by "Takari" for plugin unit testing: [Plugin Unit Testing](http://takari.io/book/70-testing.html#plugin-unit-testing).

The ANTLR4 Maven plugin tests fail:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
"org.apache.maven.model.Plugin.getGroupId()"
because the return value of 
"org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution.getPlugin()" 
is null
```

with the interesting part of the stack trace:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.
DefaultMojoExecutionConfigurator.configure(DefaultMojoExecutionConfigurator.java:44)
(called by) io.takari.maven.testing.
            Maven331Runtime.lookupConfiguredMojo(Maven331Runtime.java:37)
(called by) io.takari.maven.testing.
            Maven325Runtime.executeMojo(Maven325Runtime.java:34)
(called by) io.takari.maven.testing.
            TestMavenRuntime.executeMojo(TestMavenRuntime.java:269)
(called by) org.antlr.mojo.antlr4.
            Antlr4MojoTest.processWhenDependencyRemoved(Antlr4MojoTest.java:326)
```

### So what's going on?

After a lengthy trawl through the source code (code which is not straightforward to read but unfortunately lacks comments, logging or assertions, these would be useful), we find:

In class `org.antlr.mojo.antlr4.Antlr4MojoTest` (file `antlr4-maven-plugin/src/test/java/org/antlr/mojo/antlr4/Antlr4MojoTest.java`), the failing test cases perform the following (example of test case `processWhenDependencyRemoved()`, slightly modified & commented):

```
// Junit4 rule
@Rule
public final TestMavenRuntime maven = new TestMavenRuntime();

@Test
public void processWhenDependencyRemoved() throws Exception {
   Path baseDir = resources.getBasedir("dependencyRemoved").toPath();
   Path antlrDir = baseDir.resolve("src/main/antlr4");
   Path baseGrammar = antlrDir.resolve("imports/HelloBase.g4");
   MavenProject project = maven.readMavenProject(baseDir.toFile());
   MavenSession session = maven.newMavenSession(project);
   String goal = "antlr4";

   // Get a "org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution" from the 
   // "io.takari.maven.testing.TestMavenRuntime" instance.

   assertTrue(maven instanceof io.takari.maven.testing.TestMavenRuntime);

   MojoExecution exec = maven.newMojoExecution(goal); 

   maven.executeMojo(session, project, exec);

   ...
```

Now, `org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution` (the `exec` instance) provides a `.getPlugin()` method which returns `null` instead of a valid instance of `org.apache.maven.model.Plugin` (a class generated by `Modello` when Maven itself is compiled).

After two stack frames, `org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultMojoExecutionConfigurator.configure()` is called, but then fails immediately in a chained call:

```
public void configure( MavenProject project, MojoExecution mojoExecution, boolean allowPluginLevelConfig )
{
   String g = mojoExecution.getPlugin().getGroupId();
   String a = mojoExecution.getPlugin().getArtifactId();
   Plugin plugin = findPlugin( g, a, project.getBuildPlugins() );
   ...
```

Why does `getPlugin()` return `null`? From maven's `org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecution`, file `core/maven-3/maven-core/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/MojoExecution.java`:

```
public Plugin getPlugin()
{
    if ( mojoDescriptor != null )
    {
        return mojoDescriptor.getPluginDescriptor().getPlugin();
    }
    return plugin;
}
```

I our case, `mojoDescriptor` is not null, but `mojoDescriptor.getPluginDescriptor().getPlugin()` is, which is bad.

I have no idea why the `Plugin` instance is not set, or even where it is supposed to be set.

At some point, Maven's `org.apache.maven.plugin.descriptor.PluginDescriptorBuilder` is called from Takari's `io.takari.maven.testing.Maven30xRuntime` ([source](https://github.com/takari/takari-plugin-testing-project/blob/master/takari-plugin-testing/src/main/java/io/takari/maven/testing/Maven30xRuntime.java)) to build `org.apache.maven.plugin.descriptor.PluginDescriptor` from the `plugin.xml` resource and that works nicely but the `plugin` member is not set at that time. The data structures are not straightforward. Below, for what it's worth, the relationship between a few of the classes.

[image: Some classes of interest]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the "correct" way to build ANTLR4 from the repo is:

```
$ export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1G"   # don't forget this on linux
cd /tmp/antlr4 # or wherever you have the software
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/org/antlr*
mvn clean
mvn -DskipTests install
```

see [here](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/building-antlr.md#compile) for explanation.

This worked for me.